# How to give javascript alert to user on leaving the site/Domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, accessibility

If I use this:

```
window.onunload = unloadPage;

function unloadPage()
{
    alert("Hello world");
}
```

This would cause an alert even when going to pages within the site.
Any way to use this but only when the user leaves the site/domain?

Comment: This can be somewhat annoying for users (and could be considered bad for accessibility) - why not just ensure that all external links have a graphic - usually something like a square with an arrow leaving it - and ALT text like "(link to external site)" - and make sure the IMG is included within the whole A?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't. Most browsers have disabled that event.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload=confirmBrowseAway;

function confirmBrowseAway() {
  return "If you leave this page now, unsaved input will be lost!";
}
```

I think Opera ignores this, but the other major/recent browsers honor it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to link a click-event to all internal links on your page. In that click event you can set a flag. In unloadPage you check for that flag and only show the alert when the flag isn't set.

Comment: can we do this easily with sammy?

Comment: sammy is based on JQuery, so you got JQuery to your disposal. I don't know if Sammy itself implements extra features to achieve this.